# Problem is making a recursive function in c++

Tags: c++

A number between two currencies and one function taking as input, and the numbers as input
A recursive C ++ function that returns number  if true lı otherwise 
write your month. That is, the function f () az for at least one integer  such that  ≤  ≤ 
returns  otherwise
I made this but how could I make this recursive?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool function(int a, int b, bool f(int x));

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

bool function(int a, int b, bool f(int x))
{
    if (a <= b)
    {
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
        {
            if (f(i) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = b; i < a; i++)
        {
            if (f(i) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question well, but looking at the code, I would propose following:

```
bool function(int a, int b, bool f(int x))
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return function(b, a, f);
    }
    else if (a == b)
    {
        return f(a);
    }
    else
    {
        return  (f(a)) ? true : function(a + 1, b, f);
    }
}
```

I hope the code is clear. First condition is just to order the limits. The second is two stop the recursion if f(x) was false for all values before reaching b. And in the else part is recursive call of the function if f for lower limit is not true. In this way we call the function again with the increased lower limit.